# Variables are not updated in Angularjs Controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I need to update phone number to the controller when it is taken from a dial pad. When dial pad exceed 9 digits console log showing the number but it is not updated in Controller.Inside the controller function I added alert. So alert showing undefined variable.

### Controller

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('PosController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.phonenumber="";
    var url = window.location.protocol + "://" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;
    $scope.updatePhone = function (id) {
        $scope.phonenumber=id;
        alert('Here the number should be, but is not: '+ id + "---:" + $scope.phonenumber);
        $scope.phonenumber="";
    };
});
```

### View

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PosController" class="panel" >
    <div class="input-group col-xs-4">  
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Telefono</button>
        </div><!-- /btn-group -->        
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PosController">
            <input  id="phonenumber" class="form-control" ng-model="phonenumber" />
            <!--<input type="text" id="phonenumber" ng-model="myModel" ng-keyup="(myModel.length >= 3) && myFunction()" class="form-control" data-inputmask='"mask": "(999) 999-9999"' data-mask>-->
        </div>
        <div class="input-group-btn" >
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Cliente</button>
        </div><!-- /btn-group -->
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PosController">
            <input type="text" id="cliente" onclick="valor();" class="form-control" ng-focus="updatePhone($('#phonenumber').val());"> 
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

### Function

```js
function updatePhoneNumber(btnpressed){          
    $("#phonenumber").val($("#phonenumber").val() + btnpressed);
    if ($("#phonenumber").val().length >9){           
        console.log('validando '+ $("#phonenumber").val());
        $('#cliente').focus();
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    }        
}
```

Comment: why aren't you using [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)?

Comment: You need to change to `ng-click` instead of standard DOM events and also use Angular compatible modals. Also if you are going to be changing urls, you'd want to use $location service and get/set location via method like `$location.path()`

Comment: Combining Angular with JQuery is not a good idea, Angular has its own cycle and the last thing you want is to try to keep that in sync with other techs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is alot "wrong" in your code, but angular takes time when you come from a JQuery  world. A rule of thumb: "Don't use JQuery with Angular".

I've made a simple plunker to illustrate, how you can achieve your goal in a simple way: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/K6G95OFsaYt3AAJVujZf?p=preview

Study it a bit.

**The most important points:**
1. Dont use `ng-app` and `ng-contoller` all the time.
2. Use `ng-click`to handle click events
3. JQuery is to no use here.

The controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {


  $scope.phonenumberFromDial = "";
  $scope.phonenumber = "";

  var url = window.location.protocol + "://" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;

  $scope.updatePhoneNumber = function() {

    if($scope.phonenumberFromDial.length > 9) {
      console.log("Log phonenumber: " + $scope.phonenumberFromDial);
    } else {
      $scope.phonenumber = $scope.phonenumberFromDial;
    }

  };

});
```

View

```
  <div>
    Phonenumber from dial:
    <input type="text" ng-model="phonenumberFromDial"/>
    <br>
    <button ng-click="updatePhoneNumber()">Save Phonenumber</button>

    <div>
      Saved phonenumber in controller: {{phonenumber}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is a simple plunker just for understanding the basics. I hope I've understood your problem correctly.

Comment: Really appreciate your help.Actually I need while entering the number it need to check that condition.How can I achieve that one using angular?

Comment: I would use `ng-change` then. Here have a look: https://plnkr.co/edit/etKun9IdhGOrhcExQ6Wi?p=preview

You can also use angular getterSetter, but ng-change is simple.

Comment: Cool! Good luck with angular.

Comment: I have another problem.can you help me?

Comment: Sure, Im at a party at the moment please start a private chat. But Im first gonna react tomorrow (current time 23.40) but sure Ill help you. Im a Typescript fan so maybe Ill convert you.

Answer (score 1):

You should not combine JQuery and AngularJs. What you are trying to achieve can be done with a simple routine in the controller.

Try use ng-click in the html file to call your routine for phone

AngularJs and JQuery should only be used in custom directives or components